# UIScrollView Content Size with Autolayout

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am using `UIScrollView` with Auto-layout to change contentS`enter code here`ize value as following :

- `UIView`
- `ScrollView`
- `UIView` (`contentView`)

In run time I am adding `UITextView` & `UIImageView` to `conentView` with constraint(Top,Bottom,Left,Right)

but the `contentView` size is **not changing** and `UIScrollView` `contentSize` also.

So what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

> In run time I am adding UITextView & UIImageView to conentView with constraint(Top,Bottom,Left,Right)

Maybe you should add constraint (Top, Left, Height, Width),or (Top, Left, Right, Height)

If you persist in (Top,Bottom,Left,Right), ScrollView will keep the old content size, and make your UITextView & UIImageView (Height = 0, Width = 0).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat way of updating scroll view's content size. It's Swift so you'll need a bridging header if you're working in Objective C.

```
extension UIScrollView {
    func updateContentViewSize() {
        var newHeight: CGFloat = 0
        for view in subviews {
            let ref = view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.height
            if ref > newHeight {
                newHeight = ref
            }
        }
        let oldSize = contentSize
        let newSize = CGSize(width: oldSize.width, height: newHeight + 20)
        contentSize = newSize
    }
}
```

Just call it on your scroll view's object whenever you add a child view to your scroll view.