# iOS. how to make layout from image in the storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, uiview, uiscrollview

What elements I have to use to implement iOS app like in the image? A,B and C blocks should scroll like a one big element. I mean no fixed position elements.

I tried this way:
A: UIView with tree sub UIViews
B: UICollectionView
C: Maybe UIView, but this C block should appears then you scroll till the end.
All A,B,C block I put under UIScrollView, but A block doesn't scroll.

[image: app design]

Comment: sho your view hierrachy in your sotryboard

Answer (score 0):

To make segment C appear at the end of your collection view you can add this segment as a footer view of the collection view. Use the following UICollectionViewDataSource method to achieve this:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
  viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String,
  atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    switch kind {
      case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:
        // Create and return an instance your footer view here
      default:
        assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }
}
```

Then go to your storyboard, select your collection view, go to the Attributes Inspector and check 'Section Footer' under Accessories.

The probable reason why you can't scroll segment A is you have not adjusted your scroll view's content size accordingly. If that is the case, try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023951/uiscrollview-content-size-with-autolayout/32538595#32538595).